# Sdk version android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

Hello people in StackOverflow.

I am creating my first android application and I see this:

`Starting on August 31, 2023:

New apps must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher; except for Wear OS apps, which must target a version between Android 11 (API level 30) and Android 13 (API level 33), inclusive.

App updates must target Android 13 or higher and adjust for behavioral changes in Android 13; except for Wear OS apps, which must target Android 11.`

Therefor I have a question.

If I set the settings like this:

> compileSdk = 34
> minSdk = 31
> targetSdk = 34

Will that be ok? Since it says that target Sdk needs to be 33 or higher (mine is 34), can I still set minSdk to 31 (to support older android versions)? Or is this not correct?

Comment: That will be correct.